# How to create RSocket request endpoints without using Spring Library in Java?

Tags: java, serversocket, rsocket, rsocket-java

I want to create RSocket request endpoints using plan Java RSocket SDK and without using Spring Framework. I was able to create a sample request with the help of the below code snippet. This works only for the request `tcp://localhost:7000`. But I want to create different endpoints similar to [this](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/02/getting-started-with-rsocket-spring-boot-server).

```
public class ServerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hooks.onErrorDropped(e -> {});
        RSocket handler = new RSocket() {
            @Override
            public Mono<Payload> requestResponse(Payload payload) {
                System.out.println("RequestResponse: " + payload.getDataUtf8());
                return Mono.just(payload);
            }

            @Override
            public Flux<Payload> requestStream(Payload payload) {
                System.out.println("RequestStream: " + payload.getDataUtf8());
                return Flux.just("First", "Second").map(DefaultPayload::create);
            }

            @Override
            public Mono<Void> fireAndForget(Payload payload) {
                System.out.println("FireAndForget: " + payload.getDataUtf8());
                return Mono.empty();
            }
        };
        RSocketServer.create(SocketAcceptor.with(handler))
                .bindNow(TcpServerTransport.create("localhost", 7000))
                .onClose()
                .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> System.out.println("RSocket Server listen on tcp://localhost:7000"))
                .block();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage the *RSocket* protocol defined **metadata** and more explicitly the [`Routing` extension metadata](https://github.com/rsocket/rsocket/blob/master/Extensions/Routing.md).

Your server implementation would be updated to respond based on the particular request routing metadata value dynamically switching responders:

```java
public class ServerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hooks.onErrorDropped(e -> {
        });
        final String userRoute = "/user"; // this defines one of the route values
        final String organizationRoute = "/organization"; // this defines another route value
        RSocket handler = new RSocket() {
            @Override
            public Mono<Payload> requestResponse(Payload payload) {
                final String route;
                if (payload.hasMetadata()) { // check if you have compulsory metadata
                    route = new RoutingMetadata(payload.metadata().slice()).iterator().next(); // read the routing metadata value
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalStateException();
                }
                switch (route) { // based on the route value, you can respond accordingly
                    case userRoute: {
                        System.out.println("RequestResponse for route " + route + ": " + payload.getDataUtf8());
                        return Mono.just(DefaultPayload.create("Echo for: User"));
                    }
                    case organizationRoute: {
                        System.out.println("RequestResponse for route " + route + ": " + payload.getDataUtf8());
                        return Mono.just(DefaultPayload.create("Echo for: Organization"));
                    }
                    default: return Mono.just(DefaultPayload.create("Unsupported route"));
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Flux<Payload> requestStream(Payload payload) {
                System.out.println("RequestStream: " + payload.getDataUtf8());
                return Flux.just("First", "Second").map(DefaultPayload::create);
            }

            @Override
            public Mono<Void> fireAndForget(Payload payload) {
                System.out.println("FireAndForget: " + payload.getDataUtf8());
                return Mono.empty();
            }
        };
        RSocketServer.create(SocketAcceptor.with(handler))
                .bindNow(TcpServerTransport.create("localhost", 7000))
                .onClose()
                .doOnSubscribe(subscription -> System.out.println("RSocket Server listen on tcp://localhost:7000"))
                .block();
    }
}
```

Within the client implementation, you need to provide the encoded `routing` metadata as follows:

```java
public class ClientExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Mono<RSocket> source =
                RSocketConnector.create()
                        .reconnect(Retry.backoff(50, Duration.ofMillis(500)))
                        .connect(TcpClientTransport.create("localhost", 7000));
        // User route request
        ByteBuf userRouteMetadata = TaggingMetadataCodec.createRoutingMetadata(
                        UnpooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT,
                        Collections.singletonList("/user")
                )
                .getContent();

        RSocketClient.from(source)
                .requestResponse(Mono.just(DefaultPayload.create(Unpooled.buffer().writeBytes("Requesting user resource".getBytes()), userRouteMetadata)))
                .doOnSubscribe(s -> logger.info("Executing Request"))
                .doOnNext(
                        d -> {
                            logger.info("Received response data {}", d.getDataUtf8());
                            d.release();
                        })
                .repeat(5)
                .blockLast();

        // Organization route request
        ByteBuf organizationRouteMetadata = TaggingMetadataCodec.createRoutingMetadata(
                        UnpooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT,
                        Collections.singletonList("/organization")
                )
                .getContent();
        RSocketClient.from(source)
                .requestResponse(Mono.just(DefaultPayload.create(Unpooled.buffer().writeBytes("Requesting organization resource".getBytes()), organizationRouteMetadata)))
                .doOnSubscribe(s -> logger.info("Executing Request"))
                .doOnNext(
                        d -> {
                            logger.info("Received response data {}", d.getDataUtf8());
                            d.release();
                        })
                .repeat(5)
                .blockLast();
    }
}
```

> As you can note from this sample, the implementation is fairly complex and will grow in complexity as your implementation gathers more requirements. Special attention must be paid to proper `ByteBuf` manipulation as this can badly hurt your application memory and you can easily leak one of these by retaining a reference hence the need to rely on a solid implementation as the one provided by Spring.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer. I'll definitely give it a try.